# How allow duplicate submission in spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I know PRG pattern can prevent duplicate submission(POST) for a page. But I have a JSP page with window.history.back() link. this link take back the user to the previous page that was POST, but all browsers show resubmission warning and suggest to press reload button. I want to allow user go back to that page wihout any confirmation. The POST controller does a search. Inthe JSP page I am using:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.history.back();">...</a>
```

and the end point is:

```
     @RequestMapping(value="search.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchResults(Model model, @ModelAtrribute(value="search") Serach search, HttpServletRequest request){
......
}
```

**** I don't want to prevent re-submission.

Comment: You cannot, you have to choose if leave history.back() or the POST submit. So you could change the first with a page redirect and the second with a GET submit.

Comment: @Alessandro I tried the second solution, but after returning to GET, the ModelAttribute is empty and is not filled as well as firt call.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it now, so take following example like a "guideline"... anyway I think you should use [SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) within the ModelAttribute in order to keep your `model` still using `window.history.back()` link.

So, you could modify your `Controller` like:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("searchObj")
public class YourController {
    @RequestMapping(value="search.htm")
    public ModelAndView searchResults(@ModelAtrribute(value="search") Serach search){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("search-result-page");

        modelAndView.addObject("search", search);
        modelAndView.addObject("searchObj", search);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```